# Could someone explain me what's behind the FaceNet Paper ? (one-shot learning, siamese network and triplet loss)

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, loss-function, siamese-network, triplet

I'm struggling since about 3 weeks on my One-Shot learning project. I'm trying to unlock my computer with my face. Unfortunately, I'm far from this task.
First, I wanted to understand well the concepts behind one-shot learning and especially triplet loss before anything else. So know I try to train a network (in PyTorch) with transfert learning which will lead me I hope to my goal.

## What I understood until now :

### One shot learning

- It's a method where a model should be able to minimise the euclidean distance between two embeddings of two faces of the *same* person and at the contrary, maximise the euclidean distance between two faces of *different* persons. In other words, the model should put any face in a d-dimensional Euclidean space, same persons are close to each other and different are fare away from each other.
- This model should not especially be trained with *known identity*. In other words, once well trained, anyone could use it to compare a fixed, unchanged, photo of his face to another face of him/her.
- Face verification is the ability to maximise the distances between any face which doesn't belong to (let's say) the *authorized* person and minimise *only* the distances of faces belonging to the authorized person (1:1 problem).
- Face recognition is the ability to maximise the distances between any face which doesn't belong to (let's say) the *authorized* person**s** and minimise any distances of faces belonging to a set of authorized persons (1:K problem).

### Triplet mining

- To ensure that the model learns information, one needs to feed it with triplets that are well defined and not obvious. For a dataset of faces this leads to :
- triplets such as [for all (i,j,k) distincts] : face[i] == face[j]; and face[i] != face[k]; and face[j] != face[k]
- Those triplets are called "*valid triplets*" and the faces are defined as *Anchors*; *Positives* and *Negatives*.
- triplets such as the faces in the euclidean space are not already far away from each others (prevent trivial losses which collapses to zero). They are defined as *semi-hard* and *hard triplets*.

From those base lines, I looked for examples on the internet. I understood that the usual ways to produce triplets are *online mining* or *offline mining*. I used the marvelous code of https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss to implement *batch hard strategy* and *batch all strategy* which are *online mining*.

## My questions :

From this point I'm kind of lost. I've tried different approaches to build my dataset but my loss never converges. The model doesn't seem to learn anything.

### Description of my approach (through PyTorch)

#### Model and dataset

I'm using `InceptionResnetV1` from the `pytorch_facenet` library, pretrained with Casia-Webfaces. I unfreeze the last two layers : linear layer `model.last_linear(1792, 512)` and `model.last_bn()` which lead me to 918,528 trainable parameters and an output embedding of dim (512,1).

For the dataset, I'm using the *HeadPoseImageDatabase* which is a dataset containing 15 persons with for each : 2 front pictures and 186 various head pose pictures. This leads to a set of 2797 pictures (one person has 193 pictures) and 30 front pictures.

#### My work

I understood that the model should see various identities. So first, I tried the
`nn.TripletMarginLoss` of PyTorch and provide an **anchor** (one of the two front pictures of each identity); **positive** (one of the 183 pictures relative to the anchor's identity); and a **negative** (a random other face with a different identity).
This was unsuccessful : the loss seems to reduce but the model doesn't generalize on test set.

I thought maybe I didn't provide enough semi-hard or hard triplets to the loss so I constructed 15 datasets relative to each identity "*i*" : each dataset contains the positive faces of the identity "*i*" and other negative faces. So that, each dataset contains 2797 images and returns an image with its label (1 if the identity of the face correspond to the dataset *I* else 0). I made a loop over each identity dataset (and there was a batch loop inside each dataset). I used *batch hard* this time (https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss) but again, unsuccessful.

#### Questions

- Do I need to create a much simpler model and train it from scratch ?
- Is my method seem correct : does the Anchor should pass through the same model than the Positive and Negative's ?
- How should I set the margin ?
- About the **face verification** is my statements above correct ? I expect to train my model **without** pictures of me, and then be capable of minimise/maximise euclidean distances between any embedding faces. Is it correct ?
- Is this work feasible with a decent accuracy as a small project (i.e. smth around 95%) ?

Thanks all for your time, I hope my explanations were clear. I let you a piece of code below.

```py
model = InceptionResnetV1(pretrained='casia-webface')
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
num_epochs = 10

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
model.last_linear.weight.requires_grad = True
model.last_bn.weight.requires_grad = True
```

```
             .                          .                     .
             .                          .                     .
             .                          .                     .
          Block8-511           [-1, 1792, 3, 3]               0
AdaptiveAvgPool2d-512          [-1, 1792, 1, 1]               0
         Dropout-513           [-1, 1792, 1, 1]               0
          Linear-514                  [-1, 512]         917,504
     BatchNorm1d-515                  [-1, 512]           1,024
================================================================
Total params: 23,482,624
Trainable params: 918,528
Non-trainable params: 22,564,096
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.29
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 88.63
Params size (MB): 89.58
Estimated Total Size (MB): 178.50
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

```py
def model_loop(model, epochs, trainloader, batch_size, pytorchLoss, optimizer, device):
    ### This model uses the PyTorchMarginLoss with a training set of 4972 images 
    ### separate between Anchors / Positives / Negatives 
    delta_time = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    timezone = datetime.timezone(offset=delta_time)
    
    model.to(device)
    train_loss_list = []
    size_train = len(trainloader.dataset)
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        t = datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone)
        str_t = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(t)
        print(f"{str_t} : Epoch {epoch+1} on {device} \n---------------------------")
        
        train_loss = 0.0
        model.train()
        for batch, (imgsA, imgsP, imgsN) in enumerate(trainloader):
            # Transfer Data to GPU if available
            imgsA, imgsP, imgsN = imgsA.to(device), imgsP.to(device), imgsN.to(device)
            
            # Clear the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            
            # Make prediction & compute the mini-batch training loss
            predsA, predsP, predsN = model(imgsA), model(imgsP), model(imgsN)     
            loss = pytorchLoss(predsA, predsP, predsN)
            
            # Compute the gradients
            loss.backward()
            
            # Update Weights
            optimizer.step()
            
            # Aggregate mini-batch training losses
            train_loss += loss.item()
            train_loss_list.append(train_loss)
            
            
            if batch == 0 or batch == 19:
                loss, current = loss.item(), batch*BATCH_SIZE + len(imgsA)
                print(f"mini-batch loss for training : \
                {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size_train:>5d}]")
                
        # Compute the global training & as the mean of the mini-batch losses
        train_loss /= len(trainloader)
        print(f"--Fin Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs} \n Training Loss: {train_loss:>7f}" )
        print('\n')

    return train_loss_list


train_loss = model_loop(model = model,
                        epochs = num_epochs,
                        trainloader = train_dataloader,
                        batch_size = 256, 
                        pytorchLoss = nn.TripletMarginLoss(margin=0.1),
                        optimizer = optimizer,
                        device = device)
```

```
2022-02-18 20:26:30 : Epoch 1 on cuda 
-------------------------------
mini-batch loss for training : 0.054199  [  256/ 4972]
mini-batch loss for training : 0.007469  [ 4972/ 4972]
--Fin Epoch 1/10 
 Training Loss: 0.026363

2022-02-18 20:27:48 : Epoch 5 on cuda 
-------------------------------
mini-batch loss for training : 0.005694  [  256/ 4972]
mini-batch loss for training : 0.011877  [ 4972/ 4972]
--Fin Epoch 5/10 
 Training Loss: 0.004944

2022-02-18 20:29:24 : Epoch 10 on cuda 
-------------------------------
mini-batch loss for training : 0.002713  [  256/ 4972]
mini-batch loss for training : 0.001007  [ 4972/ 4972]
--Fin Epoch 10/10 
 Training Loss: 0.003000
```

```
Stats through a dataset of 620 images :
TP : 11.25%
TN : 98.87%
FN : 88.75%
FP : 1.13%
The model accuracy is 55.06%
```